# Z3: Modeling with Quantifiers

Tags: z3, theorem-proving

I want to prove `(∀i(0≤i<k→a[i]>0)∧a[k]>0)→∀i(0≤i≤k→a[i]>0)` by z3. The negation of it is: `∀i(0≤i<k→a[i]>0)∧a[k]>0∧∃i(0≤i≤k∧¬(a[i]>0))`. First, I set the value of k to 5 and ignore the part `a[k]>0`, and try:

```
from z3 import *
i = Int('i')`
a = Array('a',IntSort(),IntSort())
solver = Solver()
solver.add(ForAll(i, Implies(And(i >= 0,i < 5),a[i] > 0)))
solver.add(Exists(i, And(i >= 0,i <= 5, Not(a[i] > 0))))
print solver.check()
print solver.model()
```

The output is:

```
sat
[i!0 = 5,
a = [else -> k!8!10(k!9(Var(0)))],
k!8 = [else -> k!8!10(k!9(Var(0)))],
k!9 = [else -> If(Var(0) >= 4, If(Var(0) >= 5, 5, 4), 0)],
k!8!10 = [0 -> 7720, 4 -> 1, else -> -38]]
```

I don't know the meaning of the output and I think its model should be `i = 5`. Then, I add in `a[5] > 0`, and I think it should be unsatisfied. The code is as follows:

```
from z3 import *
i = Int('i')
a = Array('a',IntSort(),IntSort())
solver = Solver()
solver.add(ForAll(i, Implies(And(i >= 0,i < 5),a[i] > 0)))
solver.add(Exists(i, And(i >= 0,i <= 5, Not(a[i] > 0))))
solver.add(a[5] > 0)
print solver.check()
print solver.model()
```

And the output is:

```
unsat
```

So, how can I prove `(∀i(0≤i<k→a[i]>0)∧a[k]>0)→∀i(0≤i≤k→a[i]>0)` by z3py, and what's the meaning of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear to me what you are trying to do with your queries. Why do you "set" the value of k? This doesn't seem to correspond with the general case of what you are trying to prove, according to the start of the question, but perhaps the special case is all you're interested in for now.

You have correctly turned your validity question into a satisfiability one: the negation of the formula is satisfiable iff the original formula is valid.

In the first response from Z3, you indeed get a model; this indicates a counter-example to the (weaker) first implication you are trying to prove. If you think about what the demonstration of this counter-example requires, you have to choose to instantiate the (bound) existential variable to 5. This is the meaning of i!0 in the model; it is a new (free) name representing the element of your model to which the existentially-bound variable gets assigned.

Looking at this another way (and more accurately, with respect to what the tool does), the existential quantifier is "skolemised" away (the existentially-bound variable is replaced with a fresh constant) before Z3 does the interesting work, so it's actually tackling a query equivalent to querying satifiability of the formula:

```
∀i(0≤i<k→a[i]>0)∧a[k]>0∧(0≤ i!0 ≤k∧¬(a[ i!0 ]>0))
```

When you strengthen the query back to the negation of your original implication, you get unsat from Z3. This means that this negated formula was unsatisfiable, so the implication you are interested in is valid; you have proved 
    ∀i(0≤i<5→a[i]>0)∧a[5]>0)→∀i(0≤i≤5→a[i]>0)

You should get the same outcome if you skip setting k to be 5 in your problem.

With respect to the other information in the first response from Z3, the model must contain not only a value for (skolemised) i, but also for the array a in your problem. Arrays are represented as functions, which can be defined by cases in such a model; the "else" case is the catch-all, and the only case in each of the functions used here. Var(0) is the syntax for the function's (first, and only) parameter. In this model, the array is defined indirectly via the composition of two other functions, k!9 (which seems to be used to identify a partial set of indices relevant to the model; in this case, 0,4 and 5), and k!8!10 (which defines the mapping of these indices to values). In particular, in this model, the array stores 7720 at index 0, 1 at index 4, and -38 at index 5 (no other indices get produced by the cases of k!9's definition; conceptually, I would understand this as meaning that the array in this model is undefined at the other indices).